# When should I care setting the country code in the CultureInfo

Tags: c#, localization, internationalization, asp.net-core-mvc, globalization

When should I prefer:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

over

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en");
```

when I set:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

in my custom action filter.

My application requirement:

People from USA, New Zealand, and Great Britain should all read the same English but they should NOT have the same formatting settings for numbers/dates.

Comment: Techically, the English language is not the same: color/colour; wrench/spanner etc. That's why `en-US` is preferrable over just `en` (I doubt if you should use `GB`)

Comment: These are semantics I dont care for as I mention before. I offer them the same english means they read the same english. I do not want to care about behavior/behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

There are differences when money is shown - different currencies. There are also possible differences in time and date formatting. Those differences occur even within the same language, like English, French, and so.

Therefore, I would say it is better to put full culture identifier whenever it is known, preferring "en-GB" over "en".

Comment: What would happen if I set "en" to the CurrentCulture to determine the datetime settings, would that work at all for "en" ?

Comment: It will take some default formats in all cases - and I suppose that "en" defaults to all the same settings as "en-US". And that is the problem, because in one particular country, like New Zealand, some of those might differ compared to defaults. Of course, nothing would crash with "en", all calls would work, only the formats might be unexpected.